# Proposition 3 from Chapter 2 of Dixmier's Von Neumann Algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, boolean-algebra, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Please help me understand this argument from the proof of the above Proposition.

**Proposition 3:** Let $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{L}(H)$ be a Von Neumann algebra (VNA) of operators on a Hilbert space $H$. Then there exists a central projection $G\in \mathcal{Z}(\mathcal{A})$ for which $\mathcal{A}_G$ has a cyclic element and $\mathcal{A}_{I-G}$ has a separating element. The subscript here refers to the reduction of the algebra with respect to the projection.

**Proof:** By Zorn's lemma we choose a maximal sequence of elements $(x_i)_I$ in $\mathcal{A}$ subject to the two conditions

1. The projections $E_i \in \mathcal{A}$ to the subspaces $\overline{\mathcal{A}'x_i}$ are pairwise orthogonal.
2. The projections $E_i' \in \mathcal{A'}$ to the subspaces $\overline{\mathcal{A}x_i}$ are pairwise orthogonal.

Let $E=\sum E_i \in \mathcal{A}$ and $E'= \sum E_i' \in \mathcal{A}'$.
Further let $F=I-E$ and $F'=I-E'$ and let $F_1$, $F_1'$ be their respective central supports so that
$$
F_1F = FF_1 = F\qquad \text{ and }\qquad F_1'F' = F'F_1' = F'.
$$
**Claim:** If $F_1F_1' \neq 0$, then $(F')_{F_1}\neq 0$. That is, $F_1F' \neq 0$.

**Question:** How to see the above claim?

**Attempt:** We know that $\text{Im}(F) \subset \text{Im}(F_1)$ and $\text{Im}(F') \subset \text{Im}(F'_1)$ from the support hypothesis. The hypothesis in the claim gives us that $\text{Im}(F_1) \cap \text{Im}(F_1') \neq 0$.

But why can't $\text{Im}(F')$ be perpendicular to this intersection? I wonder.

Hope someone can help. I'm new to all this Boolean algebra stuff and I find the logic of it very complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F_1F'_1\ne0\iff F_1\mathcal A'F'\ne0\iff\mathcal A'F_1F'\ne0\iff F_1F'\ne0.$$

Comment: I hope this is correct. I am not a specialist, I only picked 2 properties (giving the 2 first equivalences) in [Central carrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_carrier).

Comment: A small comment. It seems to me that there should be a $\mathcal{A}'$ instead of $\mathcal{A}$? For $F_1'$ has image the closure of $\mathcal{A}'\text{Im}F'$ from Cor 1 of Prop 7 in Chapter 1 of the book.

Comment: Oh yes, I was careless! I correct.